# Elements positioned using negative margins are not displayed

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, vb.net, windows

I applied a technique where I use negative margins to draw labels (used like buttons) outside a frame. It is neccessary in my case, because I load WPF Pages from various assemblies into this very frame and want to use the space outside the page/frame:

[image]

The effect can be achieved by putting the following snippet in my XAML of the WPF Page:

```
<Label VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="-55,0,0,5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Background="{StaticResource Refresh}" Width="40" Height="40" Opacity="0.7" MouseEnter="Refresh_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="Refresh_MouseLeave" MouseDown="Refresh_MouseDown" />
<Label VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="-100,0,0,5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Background="{StaticResource Save}" Width="40" Height="40" Opacity="0.7" MouseEnter="Save_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="Save_MouseLeave" MouseDown="Save_MouseDown" />
```

The problem: A colleague of mine tried to use my application and **the icons (and other controls as well) didn't appear**... This is bad, because they are essential and many of my modules depend on them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying again and again I accidently found a solution that I really like to share with you. Maybe it saves some of you guys a lot of time...

The root cause for which it was not working seems to be that my colleague had deactivated visual styles. You can enable and disable them by right-clicking on your Computer icon on the desktop. Further, click on Advanced Systems Settings. Go on like shown in the picture:
[image]

Check the box for visual styles and make sure the "Custom" option is activated. The application will work again! Although I know that WPF is based on DirectX, I don't have any explanation for the behaviour in this particular case.